# using https with flask and gunicorn on Azure Container Instance

Tags: python, docker, flask, azure-container-instances

I have flask web app deployed using Flask and Gunicorn on an Azure Container Instance with the following files

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify, request
from .errors import errors

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(errors)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return Response("Hello, world!", status=200)
```

wsgi.py

```
from api import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=443)
```

run.sh

```
gunicorn wsgi:app --bind  0.0.0.0:443 --log-level=info --workers=3 --reload --timeout 120
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.8-slim as build
COPY requirements/common.txt requirements/common.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN pip install -U pip && pip install -r requirements/common.txt

COPY ./api /app/api
COPY ./bin /app/bin
COPY wsgi.py /app/wsgi.py

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/app/bin/run.sh"]
```

This works well using a normal http request. However, I need to use https as I will be sending sensitive information.

I was guided to use certbot but I am stuck as to how to integrate it with what I have and that I will be deploying this to ACI

How do go about solving this?

Comment: You will either need to deploy a sidecar container or use a load balancer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl and https://itnext.io/automatic-https-with-azure-container-instances-aci-4c4c8b03e8c9

Comment: Hello @amro_ghoneim , If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Hello @amro_ghonei, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Thank You [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) for your suggestion posting this as an answer to help other community member as well.

You need to deploy another container ie side container running a TLS/SSL provider under a container group. By setting up a container group with a separate TLS endpoint, you enable TLS connections for your application without changing your application code.

A sidecar container running the public [Nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) image, configured to use TLS.

The container group only exposes port 443 for Nginx with its public IP address. Nginx routes HTTPS requests to the companion web app,.

For more information please follow this MS document : [Enable TLS with sidecar container - Azure Container Instances | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl#verify-tls-connection)

And you can use Caddy is a powerful, enterprise-ready, open source web server with automatic HTTPS written in Go.

Please refer this as well : [Automatic HTTPS with Azure Container Instances (ACI) | by Johann Gyger | ITNEXT](https://itnext.io/automatic-https-with-azure-container-instances-aci-4c4c8b03e8c9)